# Find if Object Exists in Dbset

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `DbSet` object `DbSet<ShippingInformation> ShippingInformations;` I have also overridden the `equals` operator for ShippingInformation.

How can I find if there is an existing object, y in the set `ShippingInformations` that is equal to object x, both of type `ShippingInformation`.

So far I have tried:

```
storeDB.ShippingInformations.Contains(shippingInformation);
```

However, that only works for primitive types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use your `Equals` implementation in a query to EF because it can't decompile your code to see how it's done. You should be fine using `Any` method with a predicate expression:

```
bool exists = storeDB.ShippingInformations
    .Any(info =>
            info.CustomerID == other.CustomerID
            && info.CountryID == other.CountryID
        );
```

(I made the fields up just to show the idea, `other` is the `ShippingInformation` you're looking for.)

If there are many places where you want to re-use this expression, you might want to use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to combine expressions:

```
private static Expression<Func<ShippingInformation, ShippingInformation, bool>>
    isEqualExpr =
        (info, other) =>
            info.CustomerID == other.CustomerID
            && info.CountryID == other.CountryID;


// somewhere down this class

var expr = isEqualExpr; // reference the expression locally (required for LinqKit)
bool exists = storeDB.ShippingInformations
                  .Any(x => expr.Invoke(x, other)); // "injects" equality expression
```

Such code should be placed in data layer.

**I'm not 100% sure if the above code works though.** It may very well be that EF won't allow “other” object to be used in the query expression. If this is the case (please let me know), you'll have to modify the expression to accept all primitive type values for comparison (in our example, it would've become `Expression<Func<ShippingInformation, int, int, bool>>`).

Comment: If I have ten fields to compare, is there a neater way of doing this instead of putting it all in the one expression?

Comment: Will this be used in more than one place? Because if it won't, just one query is quite neat (I think). You can declare it as a static field and [compile it in advance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335.aspx) so it's even more performant.

Comment: Quite possibly more than one place. What do you mean "declare it as a static field"? Do you mean declare a method that does the comparing as a static method and point to that?

Answer (score 1):

```
bool ifExists = storeDB.ShippingInformations.Any(shi=>shi.Id == objectYouWantToCompareTo.Id);
```

Or this should also work if you override the equals operator.

```
bool ifExists = storeDB.ShippingInformations.Any(shi=>shi == objectYouWantToCompareTo);
```

Comment: Isn't that only comparing object ids?

Comment: You can compare anything, the Ids are as an example.

Comment: Second example will **not** work because Entity Framework would have to decompile your `Equals` implementation to see how it's done (of course it doesn't). Also, you're not even calling `Equals` here (`==` compares references by default, unless overriden).

Comment: @Dan he did make the comment to override the equals operator.

Comment: @Seth: there is a difference between overriding [`Equals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) (which I assume you did) and [`==` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) (which rarely needs to be done, if ever). Second example will not work if only `Equals` is overriden (and **in context of Entity Framework, which is implied by `storeDB.ShippingInformations`, will not work at all for the reason above**).

Comment: @Dan how do you suggest I do it then. I don't want to compare just the ids. Do I have to compare every element in the one statement as opposed to using the `Equals` method?

Comment: I dont know why there is all this talk of overriding operators and Equals method. Just build a predicate to `Any` that matches the primary key for the entity your trying to look for. The first part of the answer is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`storeDB.ShippingInformations.ToList().Contains(shippingInformation);`

you may also have to implement a [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) to get what you're looking for.

Comment: This would bring the whole `ShippingInformations` table from the database.

Comment: Also, implementing `IEqualityComparer` will do no good for Entity Framework queries (assuming you're not really going to load the whole table in memory and then do LINQ to Objects on it).