# Entity Framework Core: What is the fastest way to check if a generic entity is already in the dbset and then add or update it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I load data from a CSV file, I create entities on the fly then I add them to a `List<T>`.

The following code takes a `List<T>` and adds the entities to the right `DbSet`.

```
public static void AddEntities<T>(List<T> entities, DbContext db) where T :class
{
    using (db)
    {
        var set = db.Set<T>();

        foreach(T e in entities)
        {
            set.Add(e);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

I'd like to change it to add the entity only if it doesn't exist, otherwise it has to update it.

What is the best way to accomplish this with Entity Framework Core? 
I believe I should use `System.Reflection` to:

- get at least the ID but it would be better to get all the keys for the dbset
- loop through the keys to find if an entity is already in the DbSet
- if found then update it with the values from the new entity otherwise add it to the set

Something like this:

```
public static void AddEntities<T>(List<T> entities, DbContext db) where T :class
{
    using (db)
    {
        var set = db.Set<T>();

        foreach(T e in entities)
        {
            var idProperty = e.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetValue(e,null);
            var obj = set.Find(idProperty);

            if (obj==null)
            {
                set.Add(e);
            }
            else
            {
                var properties = (typeof(T)).GetProperties();

                foreach (var p in properties)
                {
                    var value = e.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(e,null);
                    obj.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).SetValue(obj,value);
                 }
            }         

        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The code runs from 3 to 4 times slower than the simple add.

Is there a faster way? All the code examples I am finding are all for `EF6`, based on `ObjectContext` and `IObjectContextAdapter` and it seems this kind of code do not longer work with `EF Core`.

Comment: check the id (key), if new it will be 0

Comment: it would be better to do add range instead of the foreach

Comment: If I know that all the objects are new using addrange would be better but I need to check each object before adding it to the set...

Comment: Why you need to do anything for update? If you retrieved entity from the same context then updated its properties - it will perform database update on savechanges.

Comment: @NicolaPrada  good point ;-) sozs

Comment: @evk I am loading data from a CSV and creating entity on the fly, I do not know if they are already in my set

Comment: Is this any use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905119/find-if-object-exists-in-dbset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of reflection, you could use the EF Core public (and some internal) metadata services to get the key values needed for `Find` method. For setting the modified values you could use [`EntityEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.propertyvalues#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_PropertyValues_SetValues_System_Object_) method.

Something like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;

public static void AddEntities<T>(List<T> entities, DbContext db) where T : class
{
    using (db)
    {
        var set = db.Set<T>();

        var entityType = db.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
        var primaryKey = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();
        var keyValues = new object[primaryKey.Properties.Count];

        foreach (T e in entities)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < keyValues.Length; i++)
                keyValues[i] = primaryKey.Properties[i].GetGetter().GetClrValue(e);

            var obj = set.Find(keyValues);

            if (obj == null)
            {
                set.Add(e);
            }
            else
            {
                db.Entry(obj).CurrentValues.SetValues(e);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only downside is that for GetGetter and GetClrValue methods the info says  "This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases."

Comment: Indeed. I was seeking for some public way of doing it, but didn't find anything. I expect they to expose something publicly in some later release (they are still catching up).